# How to get line number from libunwind and AddressSanitizer listed as <shared object>+offset?

Tags: gdb, stack-unwinding, address-sanitizer

I often get stack traces from libunwind or AddressSanitizer like this:

```
#12 0x7ffff4b47063 (/home/janw/src/pl-devel/lib/x86_64-linux/libswipl.so.7.1.13+0x1f5063)
#13 0x7ffff4b2c783 (/home/janw/src/pl-devel/lib/x86_64-linux/libswipl.so.7.1.13+0x1da783)
#14 0x7ffff4b2cca4 (/home/janw/src/pl-devel/lib/x86_64-linux/libswipl.so.7.1.13+0x1daca4)
#15 0x7ffff4b2cf42 (/home/janw/src/pl-devel/lib/x86_64-linux/libswipl.so.7.1.13+0x1daf42)
```

I know that if I have gdb attached to the still living process, I can use this to get details
on the location:

```
(gdb) list *0x7ffff4b47063
```

But if the process has died, I can not just restart it under gdb and use the above because
address randomization makes that I get the wrong result (at least, that is my assumption;
I clearly do not get meaningful locations).  So, I tried

```
% gdb program
% run
<get to the place everything is loaded and type Control-C>
(gdb) info shared
<Dumps mapping location of shared objects>
(gdb) list *(<base of libswipl.so.7.1.13>+0x1f5063)
```

But, this either lists nothing or clearly the wrong location.  This sounds simple, but
I failed to find the answer :-(  Platform is 64-bit Linux, but I guess this applies to
any platform.

Comment: From here: http://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/AddressSanitizer#gdb. What if set `ASAN_OPTIONS=abort_on_error=1`? It is supposed to produce a core file that you can use for analysis of addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `(gdb) info shared`
>   `<Dumps mapping location of shared objects>`

Unfortunately, above does not dump actual mapping location that is usable with this:

> `libswipl.so.7.1.13+0x1f5063`

(as you've discovered). Rather, GDB output lists where the `.text` section was mapped, not where the ELF binary itself was mapped.

You can adjust for `.text` offset by finding it in

```
readelf -WS libswipl.so.7.1.13 | grep '\.text'
```

It might be easier to use `addr2line` instead. Something like

```
addr2line -fe libswipl.so.7.1.13 0x1f5063 0x1da783
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

Please see http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html for the instructions on using the asan_symbolize.py script and/or the symbolize=true option.